# Why do I need to hit enter in Web address bar with React Routes?

Tags: reactjs

Working on a simple ReactJS/TypeScript project. My react routes rarley work unless I go to the address bar and hit enter on them, some times removing the query string.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b7vx43eg8lk09d4/RouteBug.mov?dl=0

Thanks in Advance.

My Router component

```
 return (
    <>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Redirect exact from="/" to={ROUTE_PATHS.LANDING} />
          <AppRoute path={ROUTE_PATHS.LANDING} component={PublicLanding} />
          <AppRoute path={ROUTE_PATHS.REGISTER} component={Register} />
          <AppRoute protected path={ROUTE_PATHS.DASHBOARD} component={Dashboard} />
          <AppRoute protected path={ROUTE_PATHS.FORMS} component={Forms} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </>
  );
```

And my `AppRoute` component:

```
const AppRoute: React.FC<IAppRouteProps> = ({
  protected: isPrivateRoute,
  component: Component,
  path,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        !isPrivateRoute || (isPrivateRoute && keycloak.authenticated) ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect from={path} to={ROUTE_PATHS.LANDING} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using the `createBrowserHistory`  package:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
```

When I switched to `BrowserRouter`:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

The problem went away.